# Change add to cart text Woocommerce if user isn't logged in and product is variable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I need to change the text of add to cart button of a variable product, but I need to write something if user is logged in, write something else if user isn't logged.

I tryed with this code but it doesn't work, can someone help me? Thank's in advance

```php
function my_custom_cart_button_text( $text, $product ) {
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && ! is_user_logged_in()){
        $text = __('SELECCIONAR OPCIONES', 'woocommerce');
    }
    elseif( $product->is_type( 'variable' ))  {
        $text = __('LOGIN / REGISTRARSE', 'woocommerce');
    }
    else {
        
    }
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'my_custom_cart_button_text', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Function should now return the default $text if the product type != 'variable'. You just need to replace the $text values inside the if-else statement.

```
function my_custom_cart_button_text($text, $product) {
    if(! $product->is_type('variable')) {
        return $text;
    }
    
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        // Text for users that are logged in
        $text = __('You are logged in', 'woocommerce');
    }
    else {
        // Text for users that are not logged in
        $text = __('You are not logged in', 'woocommerce');
    }

    return $text;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'my_custom_cart_button_text', 10, 2);
```